# Cognito with Salesforce - error when logging in

Tags: salesforce, openid, amazon-cognito

I have setup Cognito using OpenID with Salesforce as the Identity Provider. I am able to login fine with the redirect giving me an authorization_code in the url.

However if I open a new Chrome window in Incognito mode and try to login again I intermittently get redirected with an error in the url as follows:

https:///login?error_description=Connection%20reset&error=invalid_request

Any ideas on why I am getting this error?

Comment: can you explain the steps, what should be the redirect uri in connected app? is it your app or cognito domain?

Comment: Can you logout and retry with incognito window?

Comment: I'm getting redirect uri mismatch

Comment: please can you reply?

Comment: For some reason when we refresh the page it works fine. Ended up putting in a fix that just refreshes on error as it passes fine the second time